# Subform for parent object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I've been holding off putting a question on here because I don't want to bother the community with stupid questions, but I'm going to ask for help now anyway.

I'm quite new to Ruby on Rails, and as you've probably read from the title, I'm having trouble with my subform. More specifically, with assigning the parent object to a client object. I'm building a system for my work in where employees can register repairs (mobile phones) and keep track of them. I'm building the client object with `@repair = Repair.new`, which works fine, but when I try to set the `Client` with `@repair = Client.new`, the `:client_id` on the repair stays `null`.

Here's my repair.rb: (some fields are in Dutch, please ignore that)

```
class Repair < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :imei, :klantnaam, :telefoon, :intake, :branch_id, :id, :client_id
  attr_accessible :merk, :type, :batterij, :lader, :headset, :batterijklep, :carkit, :schade_toestel, :schade_scherm, :bon, :datum_bon, :klacht, :prijsindicatie

  belongs_to :branch
  belongs_to :client

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :client
end
```

client.rb:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :firstname, :lastname, :number, :phone, :postalcode
  has_many :repairs
end
```

repairs_controller.rb: (I've left the irrelevant methods out, I was getting tired of the 4 spaces :P)

```
class RepairsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /repairs/new
  # GET /repairs/new.json
  def new
    @repair = Repair.new
    @repair.client = Client.new

    if request.remote_ip == "xx.xx.xx.xx"
      @repair.branch = Branch.where(:name => "Xxxxxxx").first
    end

    @repair.intake = Time.now

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @repair }
    end
  end

  # POST /repairs
  # POST /repairs.json
  def create
    @repair = Repair.new(params[:repair])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @repair.save
        format.html { redirect_to @repair, notice: 'Repair was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @repair, status: :created, location: @repair }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @repair.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And this is the JSON I get from /repair/new.json:

```
{"batterij":null,"batterijklep":null,"bon":null,"branch_id":null,"carkit":null,"client_id":null,"created_at":null,"datum_bon":null,"headset":null,"id":null,"imei":null,"intake":"2013-02-01T23:29:10Z","klacht":null,"klantnaam":null,"lader":null,"merk":null,"pickup":null,"prijsindicatie":null,"schade_scherm":null,"schade_toestel":null,"telefoon":null,"updated_at":null}
```

By the way, the branch assignment works flawlessly... (It's null now because I'm not on the IP I specified in the `new` method)

Please help me out... :-(

Robin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!!

The code above all works flawlessly, the problem was a `<%` instead of `<%=` in my view, which made my subform not show up. Duhh.